# Regular expression for a language that emphasises ordering

Tags: computer-science, automata, computational-mathematics, regular-language, regular-expressions

I currently have a **language** where it consists of **elements {R,G,A}** that has a valid sequence. An example of **valid sequence** would be **R,RG,RGA,RGAR,RGARG,RGARGA** where R must always come first, G second and A third.

An example of **not valid strings** would be **RA,GRA,RGAG,RGARR** and etc where the **ordering is broken**.

I'm trying to figure out a **regular expression** for the language in which it corresponds to the valid order of the strings.

I could only think of something like:

R(GA)* but I'm having difficulties maintaining the valid order of the strings.

Comment: $(RGA)^*+(RGA)^*R+ (RGA)^*RG$